# Use custom font upon language selection.

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I have a language switcher for a website I’m building and it seems to work as expected. 
However, I’m trying to use a custom font when the user selects a specific language. 
For example; when the user selects French – I want the font to switch to “Ubuntu title” font. 
The other two languages (English and Spanish) I want them to use the default system font. 
The font is stored locally(for now). 
Here's the link to the font: http://www.cufonfonts.com/en/font/448/ubuntu-titling
Here’s what I’ve got so far:

```js
$('[lang="fr"]').hide();
    $('[lang="sp"]').hide();
    //retrieve value from localstorage
    let savedLang = localStorage.getItem('lang')
    //we check if the value is present
    if(savedLang){
      let element = document.querySelector(`option[value='${savedLang}']`);
     element.selected = true
      selectText(savedLang);
    }

    $('#lang-switch').change(function () {
      var lang = $(this).val();
      localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
      selectText(lang);
    })
    

    function selectText(lang){
      switch (lang) {
      case 'en': 
        $('[lang]').hide();
        $('[lang="en"]').show();
        break;
      case 'fr':
        $('[lang]').hide();
        $('[lang="fr"]').show();
        break;
      case 'sp':
        $('[lang]').hide();
        $('[lang="sp"]').show();
        break;
      default:
        $('[lang]').hide();
        $('[lang="en"]').show();
        }
    }
```

```css
[lang="fr"],[lang="sp"]{display:none;} 
@font-face {
font-family: 'UbuntuTitling-Bold';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('UbuntuTitling-Bold'), url('UbuntuTitling-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p>Change language</p>
    <select id="lang-switch">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="sp">Spanish</option>
    </select>

<p lang="en">Hello!</p>
<p lang="fr">Bojour!</p>
<p lang="sp">Hola!</p>
```

Comment: Would it be easier if you just toggled a class on the `body` that set the font you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't [lang="fr"] selector in css to overwrite the font property be sufficient?

```css
[lang="fr"],[lang="sp"]{display:none;} 
@font-face {
font-family: 'UbuntuTitling-Bold';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('UbuntuTitling-Bold'), url('UbuntuTitling-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}

[lang="fr"] {
    font-family:'UbuntuTitling-Bold';
}
```